# How to use hooks to load more data?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to load more data by triggering the scroll event，but it doesn't work.

Code:

```js
const CardPage = function (props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [from, setSize] = useState(1);
    const size = 10;

    function fetchData () {
        const suv = window.localStorage.getItem("suv") || "gligli-user";
        const requestId = suv + (+Date.now());
        const url = baseUrl + "/api/mainpage" + "/fetch/card";
        axios.get(url, {
            params: {
                requestId,
                size,
                from
            }
        }).then((res) => {
           const curData = [...data, ...res.data];
           //the data is always an empty array
           console.log(data, res.data);
           setData(curData);
           setSize(from + size);
        })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
        window.onscroll = function() {
            const windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
            const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;
            const $cardWrap = document.getElementById("card-page-wrap");
            const domHeight = +window.getComputedStyle($cardWrap).height.match(/[0-9]*/)[0];
            if ((windowHeight + scrollTop) - domHeight < -20) {
                fetchData();
            }
        };
    }, [])

    return (<Fragment>
        <div className="card-page-wrap" id="card-page-wrap">
                <ul>
                    {
                        data.map((item) => {
                            return (<li><img src={item.imgSrc} alt="gligli-img" onClick={(event) => { showPicture(event) }}/></li>)
                        })
                    }
                </ul>
        </div>
    </Fragment>)
}
```

The `console` prints the results like this:

```
[] (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[] (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Every time, the data is always an empty array.

Comment: Try the following: `setData(curData=>curData.concat(res.data));` use the callback for setSize as well.

Comment: the issue occurs in `console.log(data, res.data);`  because of `res.data`, which is before `setData()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `async/await` let me know if it solved your issue. Your server is returning a [non-empty](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2093#issuecomment-518427966) object?

```
const fetchData=async()=>{

  //your existing code

try{
 const res = await axios.get(url, {
            params: {
                requestId,
                size,
                from
            }
        });

    const curData = [...data, ...res.data];
           setData(curData);
           setSize(from + size);

  } catch(err){
   console.log(err);
  }

}
```